# How to check Kafka server status or details?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a command to show the details of Kafka server or the status of Kafka server?  **(I am not trying to find out if the kafka server is running.)**

I can only find information on topic, partition, producer, and consumer CLI commands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are looking for the Kafka cluster broker status, you can use zookeeper cli to find the details for each broker as given below:

`ls /brokers/ids` returns the list of active brokers IDs on the cluster.

`get /brokers/ids/<id>` returns the details of the broker with the given ID.

Example :

```
kafka_2.12-1.1.1 % ./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[0]

kafka_2.12-1.1.1 % ./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 get /brokers/ids/0
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"localhost","timestamp":"1558428038778","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0x116
ctime = Tue May 21 08:40:38 UTC 2019
mZxid = 0x116
mtime = Tue May 21 08:40:38 UTC 2019
pZxid = 0x116
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x16ad9830f16000b
dataLength = 188
numChildren = 0
```

You can put these steps in some shell script to get the details for all brokers.

Comment: I am using Windows. Can zkServer.cmd or zkCli.cmd replace above commands?

Comment: yeah, those are equivalent for `.sh` commands. You can use those

Comment: Hi, `zookeeper-shell.sh` was named `zkCli.sh` in my environment (`3.4.14`)

Answer (score 1):

You can activate JMX metrics by setting environment variable `JMX_PORT`.

```
$ export JMX_PORT=9010
$ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server.properties
```

Then, you can use *jconsole* or *Java Mission Control* to display cluster metrics.

Comment: Point the jmx metric that are relevant to the broker status?